# Как отправить js переменную на сервер?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Доброе утро есть скрипт , который при клике на указанный элемент меняет его текст. Самое главное мне надо переменную `QvizFinish` , точнее ее значения, отправить на сервер что бы потом в php файле `footer.php` , работаю с `WordPress,` мог вывести ее значения. Без перезагрузки страницы
Вот сам скрипт

```
$('.qviz-item__four .qviz-variants').on('click','label', function(){
     var QvizIndex = ($(this).parent().index());
     var QvizFinish = QvizResultat[QvizIndex].innerHTML;
     QvizSuccess.innerHTML = QvizFinish;

  })
```

Скрипт работает отлично только как отправить `QvizFinish` на сервер

Comment: Используйте для этого `ajax`. По ссылке подробно описано, как его использовать в WordPress https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: К сожалению WP в данном случае никакого отношение не имеет. Все через файл script

Comment: Вы, прежде чем возражать, ознакомились бы с материалом по ссылке.

Comment: axios, Fetch API